# How to display record or data of single item from 3 joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I am trying to display data from 3 separate tables.

**1.** product_master that contain data regarding products like image,price,quantity,etc.

**2.** attribute_master that contain only attribute_id and attribute_name,

**3.** product_attrib_master that contain data like prod_id i.e foreign key, attribute_id i.e. foreign key and product_attribute_value.

Now I have fire following query :

```
SELECT
 pm.prod_name,
 am.attribute_name,
 pa.product_attribute_value
 FROM product_attrib_master pa
 LEFT JOIN attribute_master am
 ON pa.attribute_id = am.attribute_id
 LEFT JOIN product_master pm
 ON pa.prod_id=pm.prod_id
 ORDER BY pa.prod_id;
```

this query shows following result :

[image]

Now I want to display data of only specific item.
Suppose I want to display data of item `Nokia Lumia 925` and it's `prod_id = 12`.
Then what I will have to do ?

Anyone suggest me what I ll have to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you need to add **WHERE** clause that will apply filter on resulted data.
 **WHERE** clause with **AND** that told sql engine that I want filtered data based on clause.

```
SELECT
    pm.prod_name,
    am.attribute_name,
    pa.product_attribute_value
FROM 
    product_attrib_master pa
LEFT JOIN 
    attribute_master am
ON 
    pa.attribute_id = am.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN 
    product_master pm
ON 
    pa.prod_id = pm.prod_id
WHERE 
    pm.prod_name = 'Nokia Lumia 925' AND pm.prod_id = 12
ORDER BY 
    pa.prod_id;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a where clause to your query.
Try this::

```
SELECT
 pm.prod_name,
 am.attribute_name,
 pa.product_attribute_value
 FROM product_attrib_master pa
 LEFT JOIN attribute_master am
 ON pa.attribute_id = am.attribute_id
 LEFT JOIN product_master pm
 ON pa.prod_id=pm.prod_id
WHERE pm.prod_name ='Nokia Lumia 925'
 and prod_id = 12
 ORDER BY pa.prod_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE prod_name='Nokia Lumia 925' AND prod_id=12
```